# regular expression excluding word in R

Tags: regex, r

I don't really know how to correctly find words using non-matching regular expression in R

Eg: the data includes:

```
x =  c("hail", "small hail", "wind hail",  "deep hail",  "thunderstorm hail", "tstm wind hail", "gusty wind hail", "late season hail", "non severe hail", "marine hail")
```

I want to find all obs having "hail" but not having "marine"

My attempt:

```
x[grep("[^(marine)] hail", x)]
```

-> I have only 5:

```
"small hail"      "wind hail"       "deep hail"       "tstm wind hail"  "gusty wind hail"
```

I don't know what happens with the other 4

Comment: `x[grepl("hail", x) & !grepl("marine", x)]` might be more intuitive

Comment: You're the best, Richard. Very intuitive

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use lookaround assertions.

```
> x =  c("hail", "small hail", "wind hail",  "deep hail",  "thunderstorm hail", "tstm wind hail", "gusty wind hail", "late season hail", "non severe hail", "marine hail")
> x[grep("^(?=.*hail)(?!.*marine)", x, perl=TRUE)]
[1] "hail"              "small hail"        "wind hail"        
[4] "deep hail"         "thunderstorm hail" "tstm wind hail"   
[7] "gusty wind hail"   "late season hail"  "non severe hail"
```

OR

Add `\b` boundaries if necessary. `\b` matches between a word character and a non-word character.

```
> x[grep("^(?=.*\\bhail\\b)(?!.*\\bmarine\\b)", x, perl=TRUE)]
```

- `^` Asserts that we are at the start.
- `(?=.*hail)` Positive lookahead which asserts that the match must contain the string `hail`
- `(?!.*marine)` Negative lookahead which asserts that the match won't contain the string `marine`.
- So the above regex would match the starting anchor or the start of the line only if both conditions are satisfied.

Comment: This is great. Thank you very much. I would like to give you a thumb up but I'm not eligible to do so.

Answer (score 10):

You want to use a lookahead assertion in this circumstance. The current implementation of your negated character class does not do what you expect, instead it matches the following:

```
[^(marine)]  # any character except: '(', 'm', 'a', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'e', ')'
 hail        # ' hail'
```

To fix this, you could simply do:

```
> x[grep('^(?!.*marine).*hail', x, perl=TRUE)]
# [1] "hail"              "small hail"        "wind hail"        
# [4] "deep hail"         "thunderstorm hail" "tstm wind hail"   
# [7] "gusty wind hail"   "late season hail"  "non severe hail"
```

Comment: You must be good with regex from answering from your phone and not being able to test the outcome.

Answer (score 7):

If all of `x` only includes types of `hail`, then:

```
x[-grep("marine", x)]
```

Should work just fine.

**Edit:** Per G. Grothendieck suggestion:

```
 x[ ! grepl("marine", x) ]
```

is a better solution.

Comment: That only works if there is at least one component with "marine".  Try `x[ ! grepl("marine", x) ]` instead.

Comment: Since there was `"marine"` in the example data I took it for granted that it would be there, but you are correct. My answer is edited. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

What your attempt, `x[grep("[^(marine)] hail", x)]`, does is it looks for `hail` preceded by any character except m,a,r,i,n,e . For those that are excluded, the last letter of the word preceding `hail` is one of those six.